# Number of possible interpretations for a wf $\mathscr B$

Tags: combinatorics, logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , page 93 , exercise 2.55 (a).The question is something like this:

> For any wf $\mathscr B$ , prove that there is only a  finite number of interpretations of $\mathscr B$ on a  given domain of finite cardinality $k$.

For this question , I wanted to calculate the number of possible interpretations for a wf $\mathscr B$.

**My Attempt:**

The number of possible interpretation for a function letter $f^n_j$ given cardinality $k = k^{k^n}$. 
The number of possible interpretation for a predicate letter $A^n_j$ given cardinality $k = 2^{k^n}$. 
The number of possible interpretation for a constant $c_j$ given cardinality $k$ = $k$.

So , the number of possible interpretations of a wf $\mathscr B$ for a given cardinality $k$ is.

$$k^{|C|} \times \prod_{i \in n_f} k^{|F_i|(k^i)} \times \prod_{i \in n_A} 2^{|A_i|(k^i)}$$

Here:

$|C|$ = number of distinct constants in $\mathscr B$. 
$|F_i|$ = number of distinct function letters in $\mathscr B$ with an arity of $i$. 
$|A_i|$ = number of distinct predicate letters in $\mathscr B$ with an arity of $i$. 
$n_f$ = the set of all arity values of the function letters occurring in $\mathscr B$ 
$n_A$ = the set of all arity values of the predicate letters occurring in $\mathscr B$

Is my attempt correct?

**Edit**: If I need to show more of my attempt , please tell me in the comments.

Comment: You should add the definitions of $wf \mathscr B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your derivation and answer both seem very complete and correct. Since there is not much to add to it, let me instead point out some interesting fact about finite model theory, namely [Trakhtenbrot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trakhtenbrot%27s_theorem).

If we restrict our model theory to finite models only, on would hope that it becomes easier to decide whether a formula $\varphi$ is true in some model (i.e is *satisfiable*). After all, by the restriction to finite models, we can now just enumerate and check all of them for viability.

However The result due to Trakhtenbrot tells us that this hope will remain unfullfilled. It is not possible to write a computer program which can, for a given formula $\varphi$, tell us whether there is a model in which it is satisfied or not, because we could use it to solve the halting problem.